# Why is a bathroom sometimes called a "john"?

Tags: etymology, slang

"John" is sometimes used as slang for a bathroom or a toilet.

I'm curious, what is the origin of this usage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=john&searchmode=none), the term **probably** derives from *jack* or *jakes* (regardless of the John Harrington angle).

> **john** 
>   "toilet," 1932, probably from *jack*, *jakes*, used for "toilet" since 16c. (see [jack](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jack&allowed_in_frame=0)).

Even [the article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Harington_%28inventor%29) mentioned by @ect says pretty much the same thing:

> Around this time, Harington also devised Britain's first flushing toilet – called the Ajax (i.e. "a jakes"; *jakes* being an old slang word for toilet)

Answer (score 5):

The straight dope [has an answer to this question](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/574/why-do-we-call-it-the-john) printed in 1985. The origins of referring to the outhouse as "john" or "jake" evidently goes back to the 16th-century.

> This is one of those questions for which there isn't a good answer, but let's face it, many is the time I've had to cobble together an answer for which there wasn't a good question. "John," along with an older term, "cousin John," is probably related to "the jakes," which goes back to 16th-century England and apparently is a shortened form of "Jake's house." "Jake" was a generic term for a yokel, but that's about all I can offer in the way of etymological wisdom. Basically, "john" is just another euphemism for an appliance that, as I have pointed out before, is one of the few things for which there is no simple descriptive term in the English language, i.e., one that resorts neither to euphemism nor vulgarity.

FYI, another answer references *cuzjohn* usage in Harvard regulations, this word is a contraction of the older phrase *cousin John* which has been shortened in modern parlance to simply *the john*.

Comment: 'Jacks' is still used in Ireland as slang for toilet.

Answer (score 2):

Green's *Dictionary of Slang* suggests *john* is possibly short for *cuz john*, a usage which it dates back to a Harvard College regulation from 1734:-

> 216:20 No freshman shall mingo against the college wall or go into the fellow's cuzjohn.

Comment: Unlikely that such a widely used term would spread from a source limited to such a small population (Harvard students)

Comment: @benzado The word **[hazing](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hazing&allowed_in_frame=0)** begs to differ.

Comment: **[blazer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=blazer)** also says hi. Since this answer cites a reputable source, I'm voting up. I'm sure there are plenty of words that originate on university/college campuses.

Comment: @ghoppe Yeah, but "hazing" and "blazer" are used in contexts not far removed from college campuses. "John" is used far more widely.

Comment: Another interesting thing about this answer is a word I had never heard before: *mingo*. If they can't use the wall or cuzjohn, one wonders where freshmen could relieve themselves? ;)

Comment: @ghoppe, what made me smile is the implication that it is perfectly fine for those who are not freshmen to mingo against the college wall.

Comment: @Brian Ha! I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: I have never come across *mingo* before - and there is no entry for it in either the ODO, nor the OED. The only reference to *Mingo* in the latter concerns an Iroquois tribe of Pennsylvania. And I believe the term was mildly dergogatory. But there is no reference to *mingo* as a verb.

Comment: @WS2, I was looking for it this afternoon, as well. It is Latin, defined [here](https://glosbe.com/la/en/mingo). It looks like a useful word, though. Perhaps we could try to re-import it into English?

Comment: The OED provides that example from Harvard of 1732, but interestingly there are no further examples of the term *john* meaning toilet until 1932.

Comment: @BrianHooper How interesting! But surprising that the Latin *mingo* has not survived either in English or French.  Yet *piss* exists in some form across most European languages, both Romance and Germanic. The OED believes the latter derives ultimately from the French.

Answer (score -1):

The modern toilet was designed by John Harington. Thus, a toilet is called a "john" to honor his contribution.

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Harington_%28inventor%29)

Comment: You didn't read the whole article.

Comment: The modern WC toilet was designed by the Englishman, Thomas Crapper.

Comment: @WS2 - Last I checked, Crapper invented some improvements to the flushing system, not the flushing toilet itself. [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Crapper)