# Why have Jack or John have been used as euphemisms to refer to a toilet in particular?

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

I was watching an American show called Breaking Bad and they use this phrase:

> Can I use *your John’s*?

to mean

> Can I use *your toilet*?

As it stands the origin has been mentioned [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41021/why-is-a-bathroom-sometimes-called-a-john), courtesy to @Jason Bassford and @user067531 in the comments below, but I feel it doesn’t *adequately* discuss why the particular name John is used, only on a **probability** that it is linked to the archaic euphemism of “Jack’s” to mean toilets.

What I’m asking goes deeper: it is why *Jack* or *John* have been used as euphemisms to refer to a toilet in particular?

Why Jack or John as euphemisms, can toilets only be euphemistically named after names beginning with J?

Also for clarification, several sources on its etymology say different things and it’s mostly speculation. Since that linked “similar” question was asked in 2011, I was hoping for more insightful answers. Perhaps modern usage of these phrases has also changed over time, and hence its meaning, so it will be interesting to learn about those too, if any.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41021/why-is-a-bathroom-sometimes-called-a-john

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a bathroom sometimes called a "john"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41021/why-is-a-bathroom-sometimes-called-a-john)

Comment: Note I use the term *discusses* here, those answers just cite an etymological answer along the lines of “it is **probably** linked to Jack’s...” or “John” is used to refer to a toilet. Or “Jack and John are used to refer to a toilet”. But doesn’t say *why*, I feel like that’s an important part of my question here.

Comment: Your "here" (always a good idea to write the title out in full) refers to a *different* question linked, namely “Is it really rude to use the terms “the john” and “the loo” in lieu of “the restroom”?” The proposed original question is implying about the term's origin i.e. "Why" are toilets called *Johns* in the US?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A yes I mentioned that humbly in my revision.

Comment: Jack is, for [some reason](http://mentalfloss.com/article/24761/origins-10-nicknames), a nickname for John in the US. And that question too has been asked on EL&U. I'm sorry but you're unlucky here :) You need to do *some* research before posting etymological questions

Comment: @Mari-Lou A though I do understand it was a different a question I did mention that as a precursor to here: “There has been a question on whether is it acceptable to use the phrase for better wording” (which I realised myself after changing the link to a more similar question); I will have to change the wording now too. :) thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: For instance... ***The Jacks:***  
In Ireland, ‘the jacks’ means ‘toilet’, most commonly used to refer to public bathrooms. Every Irish person knowns what this term means, but few know why they use it – indeed it’s difficult to find a solid explanation. Some believe it to be derived from the Tudor English term ‘jakes’, first used in the 16th century. http://waterfordwhispersnews.com/2015/09/29/the-story-behind-why-irish-people-call-toilets-the-jacks/

Comment: @user067531, +1 - I feel like your comment has potential to be an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Jack was the traditional nickname for John in England too (thought to derive from the mediaeval _Jankin_), though nowadays it has become an independent name.

Comment: In the US, 'jack' is never used for 'toilet', despite its connection with 'john' which _is_ sometimes used for 'toilet'. As to the 'jack's in Ireland, UK and elsewhere, I have no experience.

Comment: @Mitch is right...I have never heard of a bathroom being called a "jack" in the US, although Jack _is_ a nickname for people named John...e.g. JFK was know as Jack to his intimates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The article below describes the origin of the flush toilet by **John** Harington and also references the **Elizabethan slang for Toilet which was the Jakes** It is not a great leap of imagination to link Jakes with Jack's, especially with Irish pronunciation where I believe it is the common term for the toilet [History.com](https://www.history.com/news/who-invented-the-flush-toilet) Therefore it looks like the terms **John and Jacks are not derived from the same source** albeit that Jack is a commonly used nickname for John

The first modern flushable toilet was described in 1596 by Sir **John Harington**, an English courtier and the godson of Queen Elizabeth I. Harington’s device called for a 2-foot-deep oval bowl waterproofed with pitch, resin and wax and fed by water from an upstairs cistern. Flushing Harington’s pot required 7.5 gallons of water—a veritable torrent in the era before indoor plumbing. Harington noted that when water was scarce, up to 20 people could use his commode between flushes. **Harington described his device in a satirical pamphlet entitled ‘A New Discourse on a Stale Subject, called the Metamorphosis of Ajax**”—a pun on the term “a **jakes**,” which was a popular **slang term for toilets**. Although Harington installed a working model for Queen Elizabeth at Richmond Palace, it took several centuries—and the Industrial Revolution’s improvements in manufacturing and waste disposal — for the flush toilet to catch on.

In 1775 English inventor Alexander Cumming was granted the first patent for a flush toilet. His greatest innovation was the S-shaped pipe below the bowl that used water to create a seal preventing sewer gas from entering through the toilet. In the late-19th century, a London plumbing impresario named Thomas Crapper manufactured one of the first widely successful lines of flush toilets. Crapper did not invent the toilet, but he did develop the ballcock, an improved tank-filling mechanism still used in toilets today.

Comment: Fun fact: John Harington is the ancestor of Kit Harington, who played Jon Snow in Game of Thrones.  Kit Harington didn't need to make it big because, owing to John Harington's invention, he was already obscenely rich through his family.  Anyway, while "Jon" is a different spelling, but it's kind of funny that his success came through that name being that his however-many-times grandfather invented the john.

Comment: @ Benjamin Harman wow that is a real interesting and to have the same family name is unusual usually these family links are so tenuous that you cannot follow them.