# Does the word “uzi” need to be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, names, proper-nouns, loanwords, trademarks

"Uzi" is not contained in any Scrabble®  dictionary that I can find online. I am assuming that the Scrabble®  powers that be are treating it as a proper noun. However, after reading [the Wikipedia article on the Uzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uzi), I do not understand why it would be a proper noun. Here is the description from Wikipedia:

> The Uzi (Hebrew: עוזי, officially cased as UZI) /ˈuːzi/ (About this soundlisten) is a family of Israeli open-bolt, blowback-operated submachine guns....The first Uzi submachine gun was designed by Major Uziel Gal in the late 1940s.

To summarize, "uzi" is not a brand name, does not refer to a specific gun (it refers to a class of weapons), and does not refer to a specific manufacturer. The name is derived from a specific person, but does not refer to him. Why is this a proper noun?!

I understand that Uzi is often capitalized, but I don't understand why it should be. Furthermore, the official scrabble rules dictate that "words always capitalized" are not permitted. So another way of posing the question is this: is it permissible to write "uzi" (instead of "Uzi")? If not, why not?

Comment: Apparently, it _is_ a trademark [[JUSTIA trademarks](https://trademarks.justia.com/769/77/uzi-76977720.html)] . Genericise at your own peril (Biro only bring court actions if you use a lower case 'B').

Comment: The full (subscription-only) OED entry for (capitalised) **Uzi** says *Etymology: Shortened - the name of Uziel Gal, Israeli army officer. Used attributively or absol. to designate an Israeli type of sub-machine gun designed by Uziel Gal.* That sure looks like a "proper noun" to me, and it seems like pointless hair-splitting to come up with reasons why it might *not* be. And I certainly wouldn't let you play it in a game of Scrabble against ***me*** (purely because it's ***capitalised***, ignoring any more detailed arguments).

Comment: Are you really asking for the reason why the Hasbro Gaming company does not include the word in its official Scrabble®  word list, or are you instead asking about the word’s use, spelling, history, trademark status, or capitalization?

Comment: @tchrist: I'm one of a very small number of people who've been granted access to a machine-readable copy of OSW (to use in software-powered word puzzle generators). But my file was for OSW V1, so I did have to add a few words from later editions of Chambers (their original "reference" dictionary). My understanding was we didn't include any words starting with a capital letter or ending with a period - nobody ever specifically said "proper nouns" or "abbreviations" were *exactly and only* what we should ignore.

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers-- it appears you are right. The rule is against words that are capitalized, not "proper nouns." This leads me to the question, however, of why "Uzi" is capitalized.

Comment: Is this a bigger question of whether something that was a brand name, and hence a proper noun, still capitalized when it refers to the same thing but from a different brand? Like does one capitalize Kleenex always (in the states)? But then is the next question whether a company can make Uzi's without proper licensing to use the name (hence making it still a brand name and not a common name for similar style guns)? Or does this matter if common usage calls similar guns Uzi's anyways?

Comment: ... The answer to 'Why is it capitalised' needs two points to be considered: (1) the capitalised version has been trademarked (cf 'Biro') and (2) genericisation and the associated dropping of the capital of an eponym (eg from Hoover to hoover, Google to google) takes (often an unpredictable length of) time.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Uzi's have probably been around long enough to where genericisation would have occurred by now or not. The question is maybe more of whether it has already happened or not, and if people capitalize it or not in common usage. It looks like it's usually capitalized from a quick internet search.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, this word is officially cased as UZI.  So if capitalized words are ruled out, then this one is triply ruled out!

Comment: Brands want their names to be ubiquitous, but at the same time they don't want it so common that they lose a court case to have to sole rights to use the name for such types of products.

Comment: I just want to chime in that "Uzi" is the most common nickname for the first name "Uziel," like "Ben" for "Benjamin." "Uzi" is not merely some word derived from Uziel Gal's name but is his actual name, is what people actually called him. That said, I do see what you're saying. I mean, it is acceptable to spell "john" with a lowercase J when it's used as a noun for a toilet even though the word is actually the name of its inventor, *John* Harrington. But then I have also seen "uzi" written with a lowercase U, so. You know, maybe Scrabble dictionaries aren't the great English authority.

Comment: Consider Barbie dolls. I recall reading that Mattel protects this trademark vigorously. First Barbie sold in 1959.

Comment: The discussion above refers, in several places, to whether words are trade marks.  Please bear in mind that trade marks are primarily determined **nationally** - so a word can be a registered trade mark in some countries, but not in other countries. Also bear in mind that a word (or phrase) may be referred to as a "trade mark" - but that does not necessarily mean that it is a ***Registered** Trade Mark*.  Only ***Registered** Trade Marks* get 'official' recognition and legal protection.

Answer (score 24):

Why is Uzi capitalized? It comes from a name, and people haven't frequently used it in lowercase in publication.

First, **the name is derived from a person's name**. These usually retain their capitalization. For example, we have:

- Tommy gun, or the Thompson submachine gun, for inventor John T. Thompson ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_submachine_gun))
- Molly or Molotov cocktail, in mockery of Soviet foreign minister Vyacheslav Molotov ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov_cocktail))
- The Luger, for inventor Georg Luger ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luger_pistol))

Even though they come in multiple models and forms, the type of weapon retains the capitalization of the name, even if it's not also the name of the manufacturer.

Furthermore, **Uzi hasn't generalized to the point of being lowercase**, like some other products. For example, we have:

- diesel, in *diesel fuel* and *diesel engines*, for inventor Rudolf Diesel ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_fuel))
- leotard, for performer Jules Léotard ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leotard))
- voltaic pile, for physicist Alessandro Volta ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltaic_pile))

Popularity makes lowercase more likely, but shifts in usage are arbitrary and vary between individual words. For instance, Ferris wheels are well-known, but the name retains the capitalization.

With Uzi, too, the capitalization remains: in a [News on the Web Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/now/) search, among 2226 results for "uzi," virtually all results are "Uzi." Only 31 of the first thousand results were lowercase. So it will be a while before one can build an argument for "Uzi" being a valid Scrabble word.

Comment: So people can start convincing everyone to not capitalize Uzi, maybe losing a few points in writing essays at school and whatnot, until it can be used in Scrabble.

Comment: if you want to try that, why don't we just not capitalize scrabble? :)

Comment: If there were enough Scrabble knock-offs that could happen I guess, or if people start making their own scrabble boards.

Comment: Excellent!! So “uzi” is not capitalized around 3-5 percent of the time in modern English usage. It certainly cannot be argued that “uzi” is **always** capitalized— even if it is typically capitalized (for good reason). I can only take this to mean that “uzi” is a valid scrabble word, and I should have won this game!

Comment: @tooAnnoying It would still depend on what dictionary you were using. I read "words always capitalized" in reference to the dictionary entry - is it "diesel" and "Diesel," or just "Ferris wheel"? (Merriam-Webster). If I used M-W, "diesel" would be fair, but "Ferris wheel" and "Uzi" wouldn't. I would not allow corpus evidence in a game of Scrabble because it is exceedingly nebulous - how do I know that the results aren't typos? Why am I suddenly going beyond the agreed-upon dictionary? That's the path of pedantry.

Comment: @tooAnnoying There are very few absolutes in language, so requirements like "always" need to be tempered. You could also consider the 3-5% as common errors (misuses of "its" versus "it's" are probably far more common, yet there's no movement to legitimize them).

Comment: @tooAnnoying if you put enough work into it, writing uzi where possible and convincing others to do so, maybe Scrabble will take notice and change the dictionary. It's one's own choice to follow the dictionary or not though. They are probably aware of the word though, unlike some science terms that may just not be well enough known yet.

Comment: It may also be disrespectful to the original creator whose name the gun holds to try to remove the capitalization from it.

Answer (score 6):

Proper noun or not, this is an item that borrows its name from a person.  That person's name is capitalized, therefore the item named after him is likewise capitalized.

Similarly, you would capitalize **baked Alaska**.  [Even when the leading b is not capitalized, the A is usually capitalized in print.](https://preppykitchen.com/baked-alaska/)  Also, **steak Diane** and [**veal Oscar**](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1998-mar-26-ca-32715-story.html).  In the linked article, the LA Times has chosen not to capitalize veal.

Similarly, the machine gun is referred to as an **Uzi submachine-gun** rather than **Uzi Submachine-Gun**.  Note the lack of capitalization of the full name of the gun type.  The required capitalization is due to attribution to a name.

If Scrabble has chosen to outlaw capitalized words or proper nouns, **Uzi** fits both bills by default. [**Uzi**](http://www.abarim-publications.com/Meaning/Uzi.html#.XXU0PC3MyfU) as a standalone word is always capitalized as it's a man's name.  **Uzi** when used for a shortened version of *Uzi submachine-gun*, is not a proper noun, but it's capitalized nonetheless for reasons above.

Comment: They outlaw capitalized words. According to your answer, it would fit this definition. It does not fit the definition of a proper noun in the sense that it does not actually refer to Uziel Gal, it refers to a general collection of guns.

Comment: @tooAnnoying  Uzi submachine-gun is not a proper noun.  Uzi is.  It's a dude's name.

Comment: Uzi is not a dude's name-- look at the definition! Uziel Gal is a dude's name. "Uzi" is  a name for a general collection of guns whose name is derived from Uziel Gal.

Comment: @tooAnnoying By that logic Dave is not a name, either.  Uziel Gal would be called Uzi by friends just like I'm called Dave.

Comment: @David M the question is really whether it's capitalized in common usage. Or would you argue that it's wrong if someone writes that they are 'going to use the john'? Because a quick internet search shows that people don't always capitalize john, even though it's because of someone named John.

Comment: @user47014 https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41021/why-is-a-bathroom-sometimes-called-a-john Not the same.  John is a generic man's name here . . . Uzi refers specifically to one guy.  Uziel Gal.

Comment: @David M There are tons more examples, are you arguing that they are all capitalized in common usage? There are parts of the states where people use the word 'john' for any random thing. Do people always capitalize 'ferris wheel?

Comment: @David M And that it's different in this case is also debatable, http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/08/why-the-toilet-is-sometimes-called-a-john/

Comment: @David M There is a list here, maybe another list could be made of ones that are used to refer to similar products in common usage, and whether those are commonly capitalized. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inventions_named_after_people

Comment: @user47014 This should probably go to chat.  But, look at the side bar on that page.  All of the captions for the photos do just that.  They capitalize the name in question even when the leading is not capitalized.

Comment: @David M There is another answer showing examples where this is not always true. Here is another,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sousaphone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98429/discussion-between-david-m-and-user47014).

Comment: The unit *[ohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm)* (for electrical resistance) is not capitalised even though it is borrowed from a person, [Georg Simon Ohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Ohm). The same for *[watt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt)* ([James Watt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Watt)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen scientific units follow the SI protocol which doesn't capitalize.

Answer (score 3):

Uzi is named after its creator Uziel Gal **AND** is an acronym.

How can it be possible?

As I've discovered during my research, [Uziel Gal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uziel_Gal)'s real name was Gotthard Glas. He changed his name to Uziel at a point in his life. 
When he designed the submachine gun, he did not want the weapon to be named after him but his request was ignored.

There is another [source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/alt.obituaries/q-keeqB_Ni8/zRLABzfwQ0gJ) which states that "Uzi" is an abbreviation of the Hebrew phrase "God is my might."

Unfortunately, I can't find a source in English which connects these two facts. However, I've stumbled upon [an article in Russian](https://fishki.net/1261013-istorija-legendarnogo-pistoleta-pulemyota-uzi.html) which states that the gun manufacturer ignored Gal's request *specifically because* it is also an abbreviation.

I don't know how credible these sources are, but it can be an explanation why Uzi can be capitalized.

Also, keep in mind that there are no capital or lowercase letters in Hebrew alphabet (as in many other alphabets, though; in fact, I think Latin script is one of only four writing systems of the world where such distinction exists!), so "Uzi", "uzi" and "UZI" are written in the same way in Hebrew and that can influence the way it's written in English.

Comment: Sort of. [Psalms 59:18](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2659.htm) does have the variant עֻזִּי (’uzzi) for “My strength.” The context is, “My Strength, I will sing praises to you, for God is my fortress.” Isaiah 12:2 says, in part, “God is my strength and my song,” but the word used there for “my strength” is pronounced like Ozzie.

Comment: The name *Uziel* itself means “God is my strength.” The claim that *Uzi* is an abbreviation for “God is my strength” might therefore just mean it’s short for Uziel.

Comment: עזי is not an acronym, at least, not that I know of. The first letter could be the initial of a word for might/strength, and the last could be the initial of a name of God, but Hebrew uses the zero copula, so the middle letter would not fit.

Comment: If your argument based on Hebrew script was valid, the capital city of israel would be jerusalem.

Comment: @alephzero Jerusalem is the eternal capital of the Jewish people, whether it currently is the capital of the state of Israel or not is irrelevant for that.

Comment: @jwenting I think the comment was saying: in English, we capitalize proper nouns from Hebrew, even though Hebrew doesn’t have any native equivalent. Thus, Jerusalem, Israel, not *jerusalem, israel. It wasn’t trying to make a political point.

Comment: @alephzero I didn't mean that. I meant that in specific cases you don't really know if it should or shouldn't be capitalized when you transcribe in into another script. Obviously, you need to capitalize city names. But let me give you another example. In a Japanese game Final Fantasy  IX there is a character called "ビビ", whose name is sometimes given as "Vivi" and sometimes as "VIVI" in English. Whatever artistic purpose writing his name in capslock was, you can never guess it if you play the game in Japanese, it only makes sense in the English translation.

Answer (score 2):

**Uzi** is a noun listed in [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/220870?redirectedFrom=uzi#eid).  Browning is also listed as a noun in the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/23863?rskey=QU3NY2&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Used attributively or absol. to designate an Israeli type of
>   sub-machine gun designed by Uziel Gal.

As in:

> 1981   C. R. Lajeunesse Dead Man Running    Cyril was cut in two by
>   bullets from Weasel's Uzi.

When I play scrabble, I use multiple dictionaries.

Comment: [Only one ‘dictionary’ counts in Scrabble®](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools).

Comment: @tchrist - not in my family!

Comment: This does not really explain why it is a proper noun, as it refers to a general set of guns. All this does is provide the etymology (which I already provided in the question). I am trying to understand why this abbreviation is considered a proper noun (if it really is at all).

Comment: Browning I understand should not be a scrabble word, as it refers to a specific manufacturer.

Comment: "Browning" is not, but "browning" is, formed from "to brown," meaning "to make brown," as in "browning bread." Ooh! The official dictionary has it as a noun, so it can be pluralized.

Comment: @tooAnnoying - I can see what you're saying that there is precedent to be able to spell it with a lowercase U, but there is also plenty of precedent to be able to spell it with a capital U simply because it is someone's name⁠—its inventor's name.  We still capitalize "Jesus" when it doesn't mean the person but is used as an interjection to express disbelieve or dismay.  We capitalize "Main Street" when not referring to any actual street called "Main" but instead are using it generically to refer generically to small-town life. There are loads of examples of this.

Comment: @tooAnnoying - Basically, what I'm saying is there's a definite case to be made that spelling "uzi" with a lowercase U should be an acceptable word in Scrabble under the basic rules of Scrabble.  However, saying there is justification to spell it with a lowercase U is not saying that there is no justification to spell it with an uppercase U, because there is plenty of justification to do that.

Comment: @Benjamin Harmon Thank you for the support. I totally understand that there is justification to capitalize the U. I am glad that someone agrees that “uzi” is also acceptable! Scrabble only rules out words that are “always capitalized.”

Answer (score 2):

There are legal considerations and there are linguistic considerations as to whether a brand name can be used as a generic common noun.

Whether it is possible to 'brand' what is not a brand name and insist it only be used with initial capital letters is a legal, not a linguistic usage question. That would better be answered elsewhere.

There are good reasons for not using brand names generically if you are in the UK civil service, as I once was.  In published papers or report, we are strictly forbidden to write '*power point*' or even '*Power Point*' in a public document, even though it became a 'household' expression.  This was for the good reason that government officials and the government itself must not promote or remotely even **seem to be promoting** a commercial product.  That is a very good reason, but again, not relevant to the rules for capitalisation.

The convention is for brand names to be capitalised.  So we buy a *Ford Fiesta* rather than a *ford* or a *ford fiesta*.  But there are obvious exceptions, of which the *hoover* is one, which has even become a verb.  Another is *fibreglass* which was once a brand name of the company that invented it; another is the *filofax*.  We buy cheddar cheese in lower case, even when we have bought it from the Cheddar Valley.

This is a very interesting limiting case for language usage.  Fifty years ago, most of what came into the public domain was managed by some sort of editorial process, which enabled some sort of rules to apply a measure of consistency in a matter like this.  Publishers of journals, government papers even major company publications, as well, of course, as books, were subject to some form of checks, often subject to style guides of some form or other.  The balance of control over the past 25 years or so has been rapidly swinging away to the individual writer, sometimes edited, often not.

We have to ask whether there is any reason for trying to '*restandardise*' usage (if it was ever standardised in the first place).  By *reason* I mean pressure of circumstances or consequences to render it likely that people act consistently in this regard.  It is difficult to see what that would be.

If there is a common principle, it is probably that where someone thinks of something as a 'generic' or 'household' thing, they will write it with a lower case initial letter; if they think of it as a branded product, they will use an initial capital.

You write *uzi*, I write *Uzi*; you write *mercedes*, I write *Mercedes*:  let's call the whole thing off.

Comment: This is really discussion not an answer to the question.

Comment: To David M:  I do not agree, though I understand your point.  My answer, David, is that there can not be a satisfactory answer to the question, and this follows from what discussions of usage are about.  I do not think that the conditions exist or are likely to exist in which the matter can be settled, beyond the general probability that where people think of something as a branded product, a (perhaps the) majority will use an initial capital, whereas, where they think of it as an appliance or generic substance, they will use lower case.

Comment: I didn't say I didn't like it.  But, it seems a bit philosophical compared to an answer about the usage of capitalization in this *specific* case.  Perhaps rephrase the salient points so they point to the usage of the term Uzi vs uzi.

Comment: Relevant example of genericisation: the [derringer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derringer). Once upon a time the Philadelphia Deringer was a specific firearm made by Henry Deringer, but since then "derringer" (sic) has become a generic term for a specific kind of firearm regardless of manufacturer. By contrast, "Uzi" is still associated with a specific manufacturer and its licensees.

Comment: Uzi is not associated with with a specific manufacturier and is not a brand name. The above discussion, while of some interest to read, does not really apply.

Comment: @tooAnnoying Not so.  I said that there can be not standard rule for capitalisation in cases like this (and there are many).  We are logged on to English Language Usage.  The word ‘usage’ means what it says.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent You are right.  Both Merriam Webster and Cambridge English have Uzi as a “brand name”.  A confusion arises because, if the questioner is right, ‘Uzi’ is not actually a ‘brand name’ at all.  It is the name of its originator.  Sadly, I found no examples of how the word (or is it name?) is used.  Even Merriam Webster wanted to know why I was interested in this word -  was it following its public safety suspicion algorithm?.  Nevertheless, I think it has, in the public mind, ‘speciated’.  It is not just a sub-machine gun but a sub-machine handgun.  So lower case will prevail.

Comment: @tooAnnoying Israel Weapon Industries (formerly IMI) hold a [registered trademark on "UZI"](https://trademarks.justia.com/852/55/uzi-85255307.html) in the context of firearms and other trademarks on "UZI" in relation to military clothing, military/utility knives, pepper spray, and watches. So, yes, it is a brand name and associated with a specific company (which sometimes licenses other companies to make "Uzi"s).

Comment: @Tuffy The OP is mistaken here; "Uzi" (registered as "UZI") is indeed a brand name.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent I’m sure you are right.  I do not think, however, that the fact alters the widespread perception.  Now if I were writing a public report in the Foreign and Commonwealth Office, I might have to be careful to acknowledge the brand with a capital ‘U’.,